# nexus repository (v 3) with apache and SSL

Tags: apache, repository, nexus, proxypass

I have a newly setup server with apache httpd and a certificate. So that when I connect to the machine with https I get the welcome page and a green padlock (in chrome). I then install the Nexus Repository Manager (version 3) and add the following to my httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAlias repo.icatproject.com
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
   ProxyPassReverse  / http://localhost:8081/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerAlias repo.icatproject.com
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
   ProxyPassReverse  / http://localhost:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I connect using http all is well but when I connect with https from chrome I get:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
```

and firefox says:

```
 Secure Connection Failed

 An error occurred during a connection to repo.icatproject.com. SSL         received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
```

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Steve Fisher

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that you set all the right headers for the forwarding. Check out our [documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-proxy.html). I contains a section for exactly what you are looking for.

I think you are missing a number of configuration settings for https (SSLEngine, SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile) and the protocol forward.

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

Comment: I already have the SSLEngine, SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile set in ssl.conf (from mod_ssl). This must be correct I think to get the green padlock before I define the virtual hosts sections. However I didn't have RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" set. So I tried it but it had no effect.

Comment: I now have it working. I had to copy most of the contents of ssl.conf into the 443 virtual hosts section.

Comment: That makes sense... the https config is entirely separate and therefore as the full configuration as required. There is not inheritance or so between the virtual hosts..